# Can Muslims give their children non-Muslim names?

Tags: halal-haram, naming

I am asking merely out of curiousity.
The name "Aravind" is from the Sanskrit *aravindam*, which means "lotus."
While the word merely indicates the flower, the word is often used as an adjective in Hindu literature to refer to Hindu deities. (e.g., *aravindakshan*, the lotus-eyed;)

Is "Aravind" an allowed name for a Muslim?

Comment: It's customary but not essential.

Answer (score 2):

If it is the custom of the hindu people to keep the name Aravind out of love for the deity Aravindakshan, then it would not be permissible to keep this name. Generally, revert people can keep their non-muslim name if the name is not related to polytheism and disbelief. However, in case of keeping names of babies by a Muslim parent, I don't find any reason to keep a non-muslim name after reading the following hadiths (detail [here](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/44825/he-is-asking-about-the-hadeeth-the-most-beloved-names-to-allaah) and [here](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/126428/giving-children-western-names-in-order-to-avoid-racial-discrimination)):

> It was narrated by Muslim in his Saheeh (2132) from the hadeeth of Ibn
>   ‘Umar (may Allaah be pleased with him) who said: The Messenger of
>   Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The most
>   beloved of your names to Allaah are ‘Abd-Allaah and ‘Abd al-Rahmaan.”
>
> Abu Dawood (4950) narrated that Abu Wahb al-Jushami, who was a
>   companion of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him),
>   said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon
>   him) said: “Give your children the names of Prophets, and the most
>   beloved of names to Allaah are ‘Abd-Allaah and ‘Abd al-Rahmaan, and
>   the most truthful are Haarith and Hammaam [these names both refer to
>   one who is always doing something, whether good or bad], and the worst
>   are Harb and Murrah [meaning ‘war’ and ‘bitterness’ respectively].”
>   Classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh Abi Dawood.